# WCF and Ajax. Method not allowed is driving me crazy

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, web-config

I am connecting an ajax to a wcf service. But keep getting method not allowed. been debugging for days. and i dont get it.
I am just testing on the default GetData(int value) method.

Ajax:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:19478/Service1.svc/GetData",
            data: JSON.stringify({"value": "test"}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
             success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    },
         error: function (msg) {
                        alert("Failed");
                    }
        });

        function OnSuccessCall(response) {
            alert(response);
        }


        function OnErrorCall(response) {
            alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
        }

        </script>
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>





    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceTest.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint name="webHttpBinding"
                  address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="WcfServiceTest.IService1"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"
                  >
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding"
                  address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"
                  />
      </service>
    </services>






    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myServiceBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>


      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>

        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Iservice1:

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST",
        RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetData(String value);
```

Service1:

```
public string GetData(String value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
```

There's nothing above `public class Service1 : IService1`.
There's a `[ServiceContract]` above `public interface IService1`.

I've added so many things, removed so many things.. i dont know anymore.
I suspect it being my web.config file, i dont get that part

Comment: Try specifying `UriTemplate`, it should be something like `WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate="GetData")`. Also, `jsonp` is not the same as `json`, so you should use `dataType: "json"` in your ajax call

Comment: Tried the first thing.
The problem with Json is that it gives me both errors method not allowed and `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
What i just did was moving my ajax file to the root of my wcf project. I am getting this error: `'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'value' from namespace `

Comment: The reason of the last error is types of the parameter is not matching . I am not sure how to solve that but you can try removing or changing the RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json in the contract.

Answer (score 3):

Your operation contract indicates it is a post method but you're requesting it as a `JSONP` which only supports `Get` requests. If it is not a cross domain request you don't need to use JSONP just set method as `Post` for your request and remove the type also your response format is not JSON object change it as well, accordingly your needs, by changing the contract or changing the return data in the method and then it should work.

EDIT for commment:

First of all JSONP is not actual xmlhttprequest object request. What it is doing is adds a script tag to your page which has your callback function with request data as parameter. it mainly targeted for cross domain data share. JSONP requests return something like below

request URL : domain.com/getJsonp?callback=processJSONP

which return;

```
processJSONP( {
   resultList: [{data: "hello"}, 
                {data: "world"}
   // and lost of data you need.
   ]
});
```

Notice the processJSONP this has be your function in you page or library and do what ever you want.

```
function processJSONP(jsonpResult) {
   for(var key in jsonpResult.resultList)
   {
      //process the data
   }
}
```

If you definitely need the get data with POST then it cannot be JSONP. It has to be an AJAX request and also has be in the same domain. In this case you can handle the data in success function of AJAX request.

Comment: That does make alot of sense. The problem with Json is that it gives me both errors method not allowed and `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
Also, it has to be a POST method. GET doesnt support input parameters

Comment: Is that by definition of JSONP that it's *GET* only? What if I need to *POST* or *WHATEVER*? Sometimes one gets very bizarre specifications from a customer...

Comment: Got it. So, basically, for CORS, we only can use *GET*, right? Since JSONP is the "only" approach to cross domain calls and it can only use *GET*... It feels a bit surprising but I'm trusting your words.

Answer (score 0):

All right, after 2 days, i've fixed it.

Here's my steps, and thanks to everyone who contributed.

1. In my IService interface, I added this to my webinvoke:

   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
2. Changed the datatype from jsonp to json, jsonp only supports GET (Thanks to Onur TOPAL).
3. Placed my ajax/json file in my visual studio project folder. This will make it run on the IIS server.